# FullSimplify fail with general assumption

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Assume I want to simplify this:

```
-a^(-1) ** b^(-1) + (b ** a)^(-1)
```

given assumption:

$\frac{1}{b\_\text{**}a\_}=\frac{1}{a\_}\text{**}\frac{1}{b\_}$

Then it correctly evaluate to 0. But when I give this assumption:

$\frac{\text{n$\_$}}{\text{x$\_$}\text{**}\text{y$\_$}}=\frac{\text
   {n$\_$}}{\text{y$\_$}}\text{**}\frac{\text{n$\_$}}{\text{x$\_$}
   }$

it fail to calculate correctly.

When expand assumptions to `InputForm`, I see that

$\frac{1}{b\_\text{**}a\_}=\frac{1}{a\_}\text{**}\frac{1}{b\_}$ is `((b_)**(a_))^(-1) == (a_)^(-1)**(b_)^(-1)`, and

$\frac{\text{n$\_$}}{\text{x$\_$}\text{**}\text{y$\_$}}=\frac{\text
   {n$\_$}}{\text{y$\_$}}\text{**}\frac{\text{n$\_$}}{\text{x$\_$}
   }$ is `(n_)/(x_)**(y_) == ((n_)/(y_))**((n_)/(x_))`.

So, maybe the difference between `^(-1)` and `/` make `Simplify` run wrong.

Question:

- Why don't *Mathematica* always use `/`?
- Why does `Simplify` think `1/a` different from `a^(-1)`?

Comment: Are you using `NoncommutativeMultiply[]` (`**`) on purpose?

Comment: @J.M. I want to simplify over `Quaternions`. (If that set existed)

Comment: Please show the full Simplify expression you are using **explicitly**. also Don't use latex to format code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because the pattern `n_/x_ ** y_` doesn't match the expression `1/b ** a`. You can see that in the full form:

```
FullForm[1/b ** a]
(*Power[NonCommutativeMultiply[b,a],-1]*)

FullForm[n/x ** y]
(*Times[n,Power[NonCommutativeMultiply[x,y],-1]]*)
```

So this deosn't work

```
Simplify[- (1/a) ** (1/b) + 1/b ** a, 
 Assumptions -> {n_/x_ ** y_ == (n_/y_) ** (n_/x_)}]
(* -(1/a) ** (1/b) + 1/b ** a *)
```

but this does

```
Simplify[- (c/a) ** (c/b) + c/b ** a, 
 Assumptions -> {n_/x_ ** y_ == (n_/y_) ** (n_/x_)}]
(* 0 *)
```

The simplest way to deal with problem is to treat it as a special case:

```
assums = {n_/x_ ** y_ == (n_/y_) ** (n_/x_), 1/x_ ** y_ == (1/y_) ** (1/x_)};

Simplify[- (1/a) ** (1/b) + 1/b ** a, Assumptions -> assums]
Simplify[- (2/a) ** (2/b) + 2/b ** a, Assumptions -> assums]
Simplify[- (c/a) ** (c/b) + c/b ** a, Assumptions -> assums]
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
```

---

**Edit**

A better way would be define a transformation function:

```
trans[exp_] := exp /. {(n_/y_) ** (n_/x_) -> n/x ** y, 1/x_ ** y_ -> (1/y) ** (1/x)}

Simplify[-(1/a) ** (1/b) + 1/b ** a, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trans}]
Simplify[-(2/a) ** (2/b) + 2/b ** a, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trans}]
Simplify[-(c/a) ** (c/b) + c/b ** a, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trans}]
Simplify[(1/2) ** (1/3) - 1/3 ** 2, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trans}]
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Can you explain why `Simplify[(1/2) ** (1/3) - 1/3 ** 2, assums]` do not work, while `_ or Blank[]
is a pattern object that can stand for any Wolfram Language expression. ` (Mathematica 9)

Comment: Because the pattern will only match explicitly. A better way would be using transformation functions. See edit.